# Divergence Theorem for Centroid

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, spherical-geometry

JE Brock found the centroid of a spherical triangle $T=\triangle ABC$ with area $[T]$ to be

$$g=\frac{1}{2[T]}\left(\frac{A\times B}{|A\times B|}c+\frac{B\times C}{|B\times C|}a+\frac{C\times A}{|C\times A|}b\right)$$

Thinking of $A\times B/|A\times B|$ as the unit vector perpendicular to side $c$, we can write this as

$$\int_T \vec{r}dS=g*[T]=\frac{1}{2}\int_{\partial T} \vec{u} ds$$

where $\vec{u}$ is the inward pointing unit vector and $S$ is uniform measure on the sphere.

Question: This formulation looks like the Stokes or divergence theorem. Is there a way to quickly get Brock's result with a fundamental theorem of calculus? I'm hoping to analyze centroids in higher dimensions.

Comment: So you’re using $c$ for the *length* of the side opposite vertex $C$? Your integral formula for $g$ should be divided by the area of $T$. How are you seeing Stokes’s Theorem here (not divergence)?

Comment: Ok you are right. I’m thinking about Stokes. Then I think Greens is generalizable to more dimensions?

Comment: I still don't follow. What is $\vec u$? How is this a consequence of Stokes's Theorem? (Stokes's Theorem holds in arbitrary dimensions, and the Divergence Theorem is a consequence of it in arbitrary dimensions when you define divergence correctly.)

Comment: For example, for side $c$, the contribution in Brock's formula is $c$ times the pole of the great circle containing $c$. Seeing a great circle $C$ as a curve, the pole is also a unit normal vector at any point on $C$.

I don't know that Brock's result can be reduced to Stokes, but it looks very close. There does seem to be a smoothness problem at the corners $A,B,C$. Possibly, I will only need piecewise smooth after some finagling.

Comment: You’re right that this is the divergence form of Green’s Theorem for the $2$-dimensional case. By $\vec u$ you mean tge inward-pointing normal to $\partial T$. You choose $\vec F$ to be the standard basis vectors to prove this vector formula component by component.

Comment: I'm glad to hear. I'm just confused - if $\vec{F}=\hat{i}$ then $\text{div}\vec{F}=0$, right?

Comment: Nope. You have to be computing divergence on the sphere (using its induced Riemannian metric). I confess that I do all such things with differential forms rather than vector fields.

Comment: Great. I wish I had succeeded in differential geometry. Still working on it. Does it look like this formula generalizes to higher dimensional simplices, keeping unit normals and c--> measure of opposite facet?